# flutter desktop, how to monitor files

Tags: flutter-desktop

I know that it is possible to create a cross-platform app (mac, pc, Linux) with flutter, so I ask if it is possible to monitor if a file is changed in a directory, I'd like to find a solution without go-flutter but with flutter desktop.
To create flutter desktop app I read this article https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-for-desktop-create-and-run-a-desktop-application-ebeb1604f1e0 that AFAIK is different from go-flutter.

infact I'd like to build an app which copies all file changed and visualize into a list.

Comment: The authoritative source for documentation about Flutter on desktop is http://flutter.dev/desktop. I highly recommend that you start there rather than following an out-of-date third-party guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Desktop Flutter applications have full access to the standard Dart libraries; does [FileSystemEntity.watch](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.2/dart-io/FileSystemEntity/watch.html) not do what you want?

If you need more than what that provides you could potentially [write a plugin](https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding/blob/master/plugins/README.md), but from the documentation it's not clear that you'd be able to find better native APIs than what that already wraps.